# Using selectOneMenu with validation in JSF 2.0

Tags: java, jsf-2

I am trying to building a drop down menu using JSF 2.0,
and add a validation when the use submit the form with "Please Select" selected in the menu.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="templateMenu" value="#{bean.list}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please select a value.">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please Select" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item01" itemValue="1"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item02" itemValue="2"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item03" itemValue="3"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item04" itemValue="4"/>
    <f:validateRequired/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

However when I submit the page with "Please Select" selected, the validation doesn't fire, it just stay in the same page.

If anyone know what's happening please could you help me?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Make sure that you have a form around the content. How do you know that validation doesn't not fire? Did you look at your console to find whether the validation failed message is printed? If validation message is printed, the validation happens. So you just need to add a message component to display the message as in @CycDemo's answer.

Comment: O yes, you are right. Turns out I have missed out the message component to display to message! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `h:message` for your selectOneMenu. Which will display the message of `requiredMessage` of `selectOneMenu`.

```
<h:message for="templateMenu"/>
<h:selectOneMenu id="templateMenu" value="#{csvUploadBean.selectedTemplate}"  required="true" requiredMessage="This value is required.">
    .....
</h:selectOneMenu>
```